# Closed points on a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

I have a general question concerning the closed points $X^{0}$ of a variety $X$ over a field $k$:
one always hears that the properties of $X^{0}$ are "equivalent" to those of $X$, because it is dense in $X$.

Can you give me some hint what is meant with that rough statement?

For example, I have the following problem:

if I have two morphisms $f,g$ from $X$ to $Y$ ($Y$ another variety) which coincide on $X^0$ (as maps of sets or as morphisms?), then they are equal. How would you formally prove this?
The problem for me is that $X^0$ is not open in $X$, so a number of theorems about equality of morphisms dont work here.

Thanks!

Comment: The formal statement is that the category of varieties in the scheme-sense is equivalent to the category of varieties in the classical sense (where each point is closed). You can find this everywhere, e.g. in Hartshorne chapter II.

Comment: It's important that the maps $X^0 \rightarrow Y^0$ agree as *morphisms*, not just as maps of sets. 

Comment: @A.Pascal: but $X$ and $Y$ being *reduced*, isn't it the same even if they coincide just as maps of sets?

Comment: Good question...

Comment: If $X=Y=\mathbb{A}^{1}$ over $k=\mathbb{F}_{2}$, then the identity map $x \mapsto x$ and the the squaring map $x \mapsto x^{2}$ have the same values on $k$-points, but are different as maps of schemes. Of course, you can distinguish them by looking at maps on points over field extensions of $k$. Such points do correspond to closed points of the underlying scheme, but it seems to me a little strange to talk about old-fashioned non-schemey varieties unless you are over an algebraically closed field. I believe Hartshorne presumes his ground field is algebraically closed for classical case.

Comment: There's also the non-geometric Frobenius to worry about, that is the identity on points but not on the structure sheaf, an example that's still tricky even for reduced schemes over an algebraically closed field (of characteristic $p$).